# vim save to remote server on write

Tags: vim, sftp, rsync

I'm trying to enable Sublime Text SFTP Package like saving on write with Vim, but it is proving more difficult then I thought.

I did manage to find a solution to save files to a remote server, but the answer was incomplete.  I am hoping some one can elaborate for me how to complete this task.

Here was the example given in a previous question

```
cmap <Leader>w :Nwrite ftp://user@server/path/to/file.php
```

This works well, but it has an issue if I wanted this to work at any time with any file just by hitting Ctrl+w how would this work without manually writing this out?

Does some special variable exist for the currently open file?

For example

```
cmap <Leader>w :Nwrite ftp://user@server/FILE/PATH/FROM/PROJECT/ROOT/$FILE_AND_EXTENSION
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `netrw`, `:help netrw`

Comment: Also check `:help expand()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for a good solution for awhile I settled on this plugin.

https://github.com/KenN7/vim-arsync

It allows you to rsync the different changes from one place to another and can be triggered on save.  A very nice feature to have.

Simply create a .vim-arsync file and place something like this in as your config.

```
remote_host     example.com
remote_user    john
remote_passwd  secret 
remote_path     ~/temp/
local_path    /home/ken/temp/vuetest/
ignore_path     ["build/","test/"]
ignore_dotfiles 1
auto_sync_up    0
```

I installed using Plugged in Neovim.

```
Plug 'kenn7/vim-arsync'
```